# How can I get the `ol` element to show in a foreign alphabet?

Tags: css, html

The HTML `ol` element can display an alphabetic list of items using the `type="a"` attribute.  Unfortunately that list is always in English.

I need that list to be in Welsh, which has a slightly different alphabet (a, b, c, ch, d, dd, ...).

I have tried amending the language of the document using the following without and luck:

```
<html lang="cy" ng-app="app">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the css solution:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.welsch {
    list-style: none;
}
.welsch li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+1):before {
    content:"a.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+2):before {
    content:"b.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+3):before {
    content:"c.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+4):before {
    content:"ch.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+5):before {
    content:"d.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+6):before {
    content:"dd.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+7):before {
    content:"e.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+8):before {
    content:"f.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+9):before {
    content:"ff.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+10):before {
    content:"g.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+11):before {
    content:"ng.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+12):before {
    content:"h.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+13):before {
    content:"i.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+14):before {
    content:"j.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+15):before {
    content:"l.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+16):before {
    content:"ll.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+17):before {
    content:"m.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+18):before {
    content:"n.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+19):before {
    content:"o.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+20):before {
    content:"p.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+21):before {
    content:"ph.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+22):before {
    content:"r.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+23):before {
    content:"rh.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+24):before {
    content:"s.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+25):before {
    content:"t.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+26):before {
    content:"th.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+27):before {
    content:"u.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+28):before {
    content:"w.";
}
.welsch li:nth-child(29n+29):before {
    content:"y.";
}
```

```html
<ol class="welsch">
 <li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li><li>HTML</li><li>ASP</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>CSS</li>
</ol>
```

Also on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLokv7gm/)**.

Answer (score 0):

No way of doing that cross-browser right now. 
Mozilla supports few languages besides English, I can only suggest you writing a directive-whatever.

You can use, f.e. CSS to show different letter depending on list length...

Related: [Style an ordered list with Cyrillic letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081378/style-an-ordered-list-with-cyrillic-letters)

Comment: Well this is for a Single Page App (SPA) running only on webkit browsers, so that's not really much of an issue.  Can you throw me a link for how Mozilla does it and I'll try and get it working with webkit?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type
(values section).

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS Counter Styles Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-counter-styles-3/) spec introduces much more flexible counters.

```css
@counter-style welsh {
  symbols: a b c ch d dd e f ff g ng h i l ll m n o p ph r rh s t th u w y;
}
ul.welsh {
  list-style: welsh;
}
```

```css
@counter-style welsh {
  symbols: a b c ch d dd e f ff g ng h i l ll m n o p ph r rh s t th u w y;
}
.welsh {
  list-style: welsh;
}
```

```html
<ol class="welsh">
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
  <li>HTML</li><li>CSS</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>AJAX</li>
</ol>
```

For more information, see [Introducing @counter-style](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/02/introducing-counter-styles/) and [@counter-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style).

Note that currently only Firefox 33+ supports that.