# CSS Styled Editable List?

Tags: jquery, css, list

I'm trying to make a list that can be edited, and I'm not getting very far.

I want it to be an ordered list that is labelled as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,A,B,!,#`

So far I've got this, which is numbered, but doesn't include the additional  labels. https://jsfiddle.net/cqeah9tx/

What I'm trying to do is when the value is clicked the user can edit it and when they click out of the field the value is written back to mysql.

I plan to do that with a JQuery AJAX event sending the ID and value to a php page.

The issue I have is how do I label 10,11,12,13 & 14 as 0,A,B,! and # ?   and how do I make the fields editable ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: This doesn't actually have to been a list.. as long as it looks like it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: In each item, include an input box with `display:none`, then on click, hide the `<a>` tag and show that input box; attach a listener to `blur` from the input boxes and use AJAX to send the new value to the database

Comment: Thanks, that is the sort of thing I was thinking about.. but how do I name and style the list correctly ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqeah9tx/1/ working example, didn't have time to play around with sdtyles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just HTML and CSS you can mix integers and letters, but you can't use arbitrary symbols like ! and #.

Use `list-style-type` in your CSS `counter` to change from integers to letters to whatever (e.g. `li:before {content:counter(counter, upper-alpha)}`), and `counter-reset` with starting values (e.g. `li {counter-reset: counter 0}`) to keep from ordering like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 K L M N…

Here's a minimal working snippet showing the styling you'll need:

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: count
}
li {
  counter-increment: count
}
li:before {
  content: counter(count)
}
ol li:nth-child(10) {
  counter-reset: count -1
}
ol li:nth-child(n+11):before {
  content: counter(count, upper-alpha)
}
ol li:nth-child(13) {
  counter-reset: count 0
}
ol li:nth-child(n+13):before {
  content: counter(count, lower-greek)
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Decimal starts here</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>This is zero</li>
  <li>Uppercase Latin starts here</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Lowercase Greek starts here</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

I used Greek instead of your arbitrary symbols. In the future we may be able to use the proposed [`symbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols) CSS function (something like `list-style: symbols(cyclic "!" "#" "$")`). For now you have two options:

- stick to [the supported `list-style-types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) (check out the link, there are a lot)
- or write a custom function to add a custom `data-` attribute to each `<li>` that translates the `li` value into your custom markers, and then use populate that value into the `li:before`'s `content`. Amazingly @Blender has already written that script up in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082088/1241736

Comment: @rocket just in case you saw the first version of my answer: I've revised it to use counters in pseudoelements

Comment: Thanks this really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an input field, no need to over do it :)

```js
$('ol.rectangle-list a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input').select();
});

$('ol.rectangle-list input').blur(function(e) {
    //$(this).attr('readonly', true);
    console.log('MAKE AJAX REQUEST');
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 500px;
   }

   /* -------------------------------------- */

   ol{
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style: none;
    *list-style: decimal;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   }

   ol ol{
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
   }

   /* -------------------------------------- */

   .rectangle-list a{
     font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
        color: #444;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
    background: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out; 
   }

   .rectangle-list a:hover{
    background: #eee;
   } 

   .rectangle-list a:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -2.5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1em;
    background: #fa8072;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
   }
   
   .rectangle-list a:after{
    position: absolute; 
    content: '';
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    left: -1em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;    
   }

   .rectangle-list a:hover:after{
    left: -.5em;
    border-left-color: #fa8072;    
   }
      
      .rectangle-list input{
        border: none;
        font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
        color: #444;
        background: transparent;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="rectangle-list">
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
 <li><a href="#"><input type="text" value="List item"></a></li>   
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks that will help.